# Zend Framework MySQL Update Column

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Is there any way to do what the following code does, using Zend_Db_Table_Abstract?

```
UPDATE table SET value=value+1 WHERE value < 10;
```

I tried something like:

```
$tableModel->update(array('value=value+1'),'value<10');
```

but no success.

I could fetch the data in a `SELECT` and then just add 1 to that, but that's no option, cause it's very slow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first argument array is an associative mapping of columns and values. If you're not using an absolute value, i.e. you want to use an expression or function, you need to use [Zend_Db_Expr](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns-expr). The following should increment the 'value' column of any rows with a current value under 10.

```
$tableModel->update(array(
    'value' => new Zend_Db_Expr('value + 1')
), 'value < 10');
```